# Restkit Orphaned deletions does not work on relationships with RKAssignmentPolicyUnion

Tags: ios, restkit

I am currently using restkit in one of my iOS projects and I have been wrestling with deleting orphaned objects that have relationships with RKAssignmentPolicy.

**The following example should help explain my problem:**

I have an entity `User` with a relationship `friends`. The `friends` relationship mapping has an assignmentPolicy `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion` to `User` entity. The resource `friends` is paginated on every request so the response is merged with the existing list of friends.

**eg.**

Page 1 response { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

local_database  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

Page 2 response { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }

local_database  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }

Lets say I refresh my `friends` list and the response is { 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 }, my local database does not delete the orphaned objects { 1, 6, 8, 9, 10 }.

After digging through `Restkit` I found out this line https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/61ea93b0ee22cef55c9cbd33ed5731f85e27b2b0/Code/Network/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m#L754 returns 
not only the mapped objects from the response but also the objects in my local_database while using `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion`.

Has anyone come across this problem and how did you go about solving it? Thanks in advance :).

**PS:** I have a fetch request to handle deletion of orphaned objects. Also I found this issue on github related to my problem https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2032

Comment: Can you remove everything from the relationship before you start the pagination and then delete anything without a relationship when the update is done?

Comment: I am guessing you wont me to empty the relationship right before i make the pagination request, but wouldnt that lead to bad user experience when the request fails during the refreshing process. A user would have a list full of `friends` but then in their attempt to refresh the list everything gets deleted because the request failed. My idea was to save everything from the relationship before pagination in a variable and then perform an NSSet operation to remove anything thats not in the updated list, that way the user's screen doesn't go blank during the refresh process. Hope I am makng sense

Comment: I just figured what I wrote above will not work because the updated list will be the same as the list saved before pagination because of `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion`, ignore my idea. I would like to move forward with your idea @Wain but my only problem has to do with the user experience side of it

Comment: You would need to paginated into a new list which starts empty and then copy into the true list on completion and deal with the removals at that point in time

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Sadly I did not, I switched over to MagicalRecord for my data mapping.